# error when creating a new container inside page.wrapper in magento2

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I'm trying to create a container inside page.wrapper to contain some custom blocks for my checkout page.

When I try the following in

> app/design/frontend/MyTheme/myname/Magento_Theme/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="logo-container">
        <referenceBlock name="onestepcheckout-logo" remove="true" />
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="footer-custom3" as="footer" after="main.content" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" >
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

I get an error that

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The 'footer-custom3' is not a child of 'page.wrapper'.

How do I make it a child of **page.wrapper**?

Also if I use it as a child of main.content as in the following it shows up

```
<referenceContainer name="main.content">
    <container name="footer-custom3" as="footer" after="main.content" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer" >
        <block class="CleverSoft\Base\Block\Template" name="footer_block" template="html/footer.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="footer.store_switcher" template="switch/stores.phtml" />
            <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="footer.newsletter" template="subscribe_footer.phtml" />
        </block>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Could someone explain to me why this is not working for `page.wrapper`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of **page.wrapper** already has had a container with an alias is **footer**:

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

When you try to add a container with the same alias **footer**, it is not added into list children of **page.wrapper**, it means when layout call **getChildOffSet('footer')** this will return **footer-container** instead of **footer-custom3**

You can read more detail in `\Magento\Framework\Data\Structure::_getChildOffset` and you can see the index of this

```
$index = array_search($childId, array_keys($this->getChildren($parentId)));
```

will be return false with `$childId='footer-custom3'`

I suggest you should change the alias to something else like as="footer-3" or your should remove **footer-container** before adding **footer-custom3**

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>
```

If you see my answer is useful, please give me a vote

Thanks

Comment: Nice, thanks for the detailed explanation. The error message was confusing me. I was thinking maybe I was missing something similar to magento 1 where you had to also `echo $this->getChildHtml('block_name')` in some cases but it was much simpler. Much appreciated